# Can vortices be formed in a non-viscous fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vortex

As I understand vortices form when a part of a fluid is moving with greater velocity, than its neighbour parts, so its neighbour parts that are moving slower ''want to slow down its faster neighbour part(s)'' and faster parts ''want to continue moving faster'', so faster and slower moving parts ''resolve this problem'' in a way that faster moving parts are circling around a point at smaller radius than slower moving parts (which are circulating around the same point at a larger radius), so the vortices are formed. Intermolecular forces are connecting parts (faster moving and slower moving) of the fluid together and the weaker they are, the weaker is the viscosity of the fluid. So if the fluid is non-viscous, the intermolecular forces in the fluid are 0? If they are 0, faster and slower moving parts almost don't interact with each other, so the vortex doesn't form? Is my understanding of this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

- viscosity, even in small regions of the domain, is usually needed to create vorticity;
- if thin regions of large vorticity exist in a domain of otherwise
  irrotational flow, its possible to identify the rotational regions as vortices
- once created, if the viscous effects outside them are negligible, the intensity of these vortices tends to be conserved.

Anyway, I feel that some more details can be useful.

### Model to describe nature

We usually explain the nature with models. In fluid dynamics, in many cases of interest, its possible to work with (incompressible) **inviscid irrotational flows** where the influence of viscosity and vorticity are zero **almost everywhere**. This model usually is a good model for flows:

- at high Reynolds number, where effects of viscous stress are almost everywhere negligible w.r.t. inertia,
- around streamlined bodies, so that no flow separation occurs.

In such conditions, vorticity and viscous effects are confined to very thin regions, namely thin boundary layers on the surface of solid bodies and free wakes in the domain.

Mathematically, these regions can be represented as finite jump of velocity in a infinitesimal thickness, and thus infinite vorticity: these mathematical models are lumping vorticity in these thin regions, while the rest of the domain is modelled as irrotational.

### What is a vortex?

While there is no unambiguous answer in fluid dynamics, it's possible to identify a vortex with the infinitesimal infinite-vorticity regions when using the (quasi)-irrotational model of the fluid described above.

Within this model some theorems exist, namely Kelvin and Helmholtz theorems, stating some sort of **conservation of vortex intensity**:

- **Helmholtz** theorems tell us that:

  - the intensity of a vortex line is constant in space
  - and thus, a vortex line is either closed (vortex ring) or originates/ends on the boundary of the fluid domain (as an example on solid walls), or they can merge like (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2kvEC852MI)
- **Kelvin** theorem tells us that the circuitation along a closed material curve is constant in time

**Vortex rings**
[image: 1]

**Vortex originating from solid bodies**
|            |            |            |
|------------|------------|------------|
| [image: 2]  | [image: 3]  | [image: 4]  |

**Merging vortices**
|            |            |
|------------|------------|
| [image: 5]  | [image: 6]  |

Comment: "Mathematically, these regions can be represented as finite jump of velocity in a infinitesimal thickness, and thus infinite vorticity: these mathematical models are lumping vorticity in these thin regions, while the rest of the domain is modelled as irrotational." Not true. The vorticity would be proportional to the velocity jump.

Comment: That's true, they're proportional to a Dirac delta, if you want an approximation as a generalized function, and thus infinite on a point/line/surface. Finite jump across infinitesimal distance, you can tell me that $c/0 \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: I'm simply pointing out that a vortex sheet (ie. a surface with finite vortex density distributed on it) has a finite velocity jump across it.

Comment: Please, read carefully your first comment. Then you should easily realize that your sentence "Not true" is false and unsubstantiated, and no way it's not equivalent to your second comment